# How to restrict dialog dismissal android

Tags: java, android

I want to restrict dismissal of dialogs in my android app to a particular event. How can I go about it.
I want the dialog to dismiss only after a certain process is completed.
such that if the user clicks outside the dialog the dialog does not close.

Comment: set dialog cancelable to false

Answer (score 0):

For prevent close on outside touch

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Override the onTouchEvent Event of the dialog

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
    
    //certain process
   }  
   return false;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to prevent dialog from being dismissed

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

And use this to dismiss after your process is complete

```
dialog.dismiss();
```